# Setting up a kafka cluster on a single machine and configuration

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-cluster

Trying to set a kafka cluster on a single machine following some online tutorials and edited the config/server.properties to choose the port 9091 for one broker and for another broker using 9092 and the respective zookeepers for kafka brokers are 2180 and 2181(There is no issue with starting the zoo-keepers) but the broker connecting to 2180 behaves different and unable to start, log is as below

```
  advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9091
        advertised.port = null
        alter.config.policy.class.name = null
        alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
        alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        authorizer.class.name =
        auto.create.topics.enable = true
        auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
        background.threads = 10
        broker.id = 1
        broker.id.generation.enable = true
        broker.rack = null
        client.quota.callback.class = null
        compression.type = producer
        connection.failed.authentication.delay.ms = 100
        connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
        connections.max.reauth.ms = 0
        control.plane.listener.name = null
        controlled.shutdown.enable = true
        controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
        controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
        controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        create.topic.policy.class.name = null
        default.replication.factor = 1
        delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms = 3600000
        delegation.token.expiry.time.ms = 86400000
        delegation.token.master.key = null
        delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms = 604800000
        delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
        delete.topic.enable = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 57671680
        fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
        group.max.session.timeout.ms = 1800000
        group.max.size = 2147483647
        group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
        host.name =
        inter.broker.listener.name = null
        inter.broker.protocol.version = 2.6-IV0
        kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs = 10
        kafka.metrics.reporters = []
        leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
        leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
        listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
        listeners = null
        log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
        log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
        log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
        log.cleaner.enable = true
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
        log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
        log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
        log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
        log.cleaner.threads = 1
        log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
        log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
        log.dirs = C:/kafka_2.13-2.6.0_1/logs
        log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
        log.flush.interval.ms = null
        log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
        log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
        log.message.downconversion.enable = true
        log.message.format.version = 2.6-IV0
        log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
        log.preallocate = false
        log.retention.bytes = -1
        log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
        log.retention.hours = 168
        log.retention.minutes = null
        log.retention.ms = null
        log.roll.hours = 168
        log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
        log.roll.jitter.ms = null
        log.roll.ms = null
        log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
        log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
        max.connections = 2147483647
        max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
        max.connections.per.ip.overrides =
        max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
        message.max.bytes = 1048588
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        min.insync.replicas = 1
        num.io.threads = 8
        num.network.threads = 3
        num.partitions = 1
        num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
        num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
        num.replica.fetchers = 1
        offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
        offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
        offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
        offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
        offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
        offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
        offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
        offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
        offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
        offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
        password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
        password.encoder.iterations = 4096
        password.encoder.key.length = 128
        password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
        password.encoder.old.secret = null
        password.encoder.secret = null
        port = 9092
        principal.builder.class = null
        producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        queued.max.request.bytes = -1
        queued.max.requests = 500
        quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.window.num = 11
        quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
        replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
        replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
        replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
        replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
        replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
        replica.lag.time.max.ms = 30000
        replica.selector.class = null
        replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        replication.quota.window.num = 11
        replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
        sasl.server.callback.handler.class = null
        security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
        socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
        socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
        ssl.cipher.suites = []
        ssl.client.auth = none
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.principal.mapping.rules = DEFAULT
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 10000
        transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
        transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
        transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
        transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
        transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
        transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
        transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
        transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
        unclean.leader.election.enable = false
        zookeeper.clientCnxnSocket = null
        zookeeper.connect = localhost:2180
        zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 18000
        zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
        zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 18000
        zookeeper.set.acl = false
        zookeeper.ssl.cipher.suites = null
        zookeeper.ssl.client.enable = false
        zookeeper.ssl.crl.enable = false
        zookeeper.ssl.enabled.protocols = null
        zookeeper.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = HTTPS
        zookeeper.ssl.keystore.location = null
        zookeeper.ssl.keystore.password = null
        zookeeper.ssl.keystore.type = null
        zookeeper.ssl.ocsp.enable = false
        zookeeper.ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
        zookeeper.ssl.truststore.location = null
        zookeeper.ssl.truststore.password = null
        zookeeper.ssl.truststore.type = null
        zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2021-03-15 00:02:39,335] INFO KafkaConfig values:
        advertised.host.name = null
        advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9091
        advertised.port = null
        alter.config.policy.class.name = null
        alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
        alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        authorizer.class.name =
        auto.create.topics.enable = true
        auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
        background.threads = 10
        broker.id = 1
        broker.id.generation.enable = true
        broker.rack = null
        client.quota.callback.class = null
        compression.type = producer
        connection.failed.authentication.delay.ms = 100
        connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
        connections.max.reauth.ms = 0
        control.plane.listener.name = null
        controlled.shutdown.enable = true
        controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
        controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
        controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        create.topic.policy.class.name = null
        default.replication.factor = 1
        delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms = 3600000
        delegation.token.expiry.time.ms = 86400000
        delegation.token.master.key = null
        delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms = 604800000
        delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
        delete.topic.enable = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 57671680
        fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
        group.max.session.timeout.ms = 1800000
        group.max.size = 2147483647
        group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
        host.name =
        inter.broker.listener.name = null
        inter.broker.protocol.version = 2.6-IV0
        kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs = 10
        kafka.metrics.reporters = []
        leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
        leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
        listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
        listeners = null
        log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
        log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
        log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
        log.cleaner.enable = true
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
        log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
        log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
        log.cleaner.max.compaction.lag.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
        log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
        log.cleaner.threads = 1
        log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
        log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
        log.dirs = C:/kafka_2.13-2.6.0_1/logs
        log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
        log.flush.interval.ms = null
        log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
        log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
        log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
        log.message.downconversion.enable = true
        log.message.format.version = 2.6-IV0
        log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
        log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
        log.preallocate = false
        log.retention.bytes = -1
        log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
        log.retention.hours = 168
        log.retention.minutes = null
        log.retention.ms = null
        log.roll.hours = 168
        log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
        log.roll.jitter.ms = null
        log.roll.ms = null
        log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
        log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
        max.connections = 2147483647
        max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
        max.connections.per.ip.overrides =
        max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
        message.max.bytes = 1048588
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        min.insync.replicas = 1
        num.io.threads = 8
        num.network.threads = 3
        num.partitions = 1
        num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
        num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
        num.replica.fetchers = 1
        offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
        offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
        offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
        offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
        offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
        offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
        offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
        offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
        offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
        offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
        password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
        password.encoder.iterations = 4096
        password.encoder.key.length = 128
        password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
        password.encoder.old.secret = null
        password.encoder.secret = null
        port = 9092
        principal.builder.class = null
        producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
        queued.max.request.bytes = -1
        queued.max.requests = 500
        quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
        quota.window.num = 11
        quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
        replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
        replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
        replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
        replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
        replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
        replica.lag.time.max.ms = 30000
        replica.selector.class = null
        replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
        replication.quota.window.num = 11
        replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
        sasl.server.callback.handler.class = null
        security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
        socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
        socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
        ssl.cipher.suites = []
        ssl.client.auth = none
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.principal.mapping.rules = DEFAULT
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 10000
        transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
        transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
        transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
        transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
        transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
        transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
        transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
        transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
        unclean.leader.election.enable = false
        zookeeper.clientCnxnSocket = null
        zookeeper.connect = localhost:2180
        zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 18000
        zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
        zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 18000
        zookeeper.set.acl = false
        zookeeper.ssl.cipher.suites = null
        zookeeper.ssl.client.enable = false
        zookeeper.ssl.crl.enable = false
        zookeeper.ssl.enabled.protocols = null
        zookeeper.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = HTTPS
        zookeeper.ssl.keystore.location = null
        zookeeper.ssl.keystore.password = null
        zookeeper.ssl.keystore.type = null
        zookeeper.ssl.ocsp.enable = false
        zookeeper.ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
        zookeeper.ssl.truststore.location = null
        zookeeper.ssl.truststore.password = null
        zookeeper.ssl.truststore.type = null
        zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
```

We can see advertised listeners pointing to 9091 but we still have ** port = 9092 ** in the above log, When everything removed to port 9092 is changed to 9091 under server.properties, Why does it consider 9092 as the port (This resulting in port already in use as the other broker is using 9092)
Please let me know the issue and how to make a cluster configuration proper. Thanks in advance.

In the bootstrap servers config, both the urls are provided separated by comma

```
public static void main(String k[]) {
        Properties prop=new Properties();
        prop.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9091,localhost:9092");
        prop.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        prop.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        KafkaProducer<String,String> kp=new KafkaProducer<>(prop);
        ProducerRecord<String,String> rec=new ProducerRecord<>("fst_tps","one");
        kp.send(rec, new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata arg0, Exception arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println(arg0.topic()+" "+arg0.offset()+" "+arg0.partition());
            }
            
        });
        kp.flush();
        kp.close();
    }
```

Comment: You should never use an even number of Zookeeper servers. Why do you want to use more than one broker on the same machine?

Comment: @OneCricketeer- To understand acks property and the behavior to see when i stop one broker, there should n't be an acknowledgement saying that all the brokers have received the message. To get more practical knowledge, trying to make a cluster as i have only one laptop. Is there any constraint on using even number of zookeeper

Comment: Can you show all relevant properties files? Does this documentation section help? http://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/#quickstart_multibroker

Comment: @OneCricketeer-- Thank you for the information, i included port=9091 in the server.properties of other broker and both started working. To be more clear, there are two brokers, broker-0 (zookeeper-2181,port-9092), broker-1 (zookeeper-2180,port-9091) and when included in the java code, the first message went into broker-0 and then executed the program again,it went into broker-1, Still wonder is it a cluster now ? , however both the nodes have their own zookeepers. code in the edited section.

Comment: I wasn't asking for code, just the server property files for Zookeeper and the brokers. Again, never use even number of Zookeeper servers. You only need one here. More specifically, you don't need to have the same number of Zookeeper servers as Kafka brokers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data goes to one broker, then the other, that depends on your partition count and excludes any connection issues

> Still wonder is it a cluster now ? , however both the nodes have their own zookeepers

First, as mentioned in the documentation, `zookeeper.connect` needs to be the same string for a cluster to be formed. You only need one Zookeeper server, so stop the one on 2180 and just use `localhost:2181`

Once both Kafka brokers are running, you can use `kafkacat -L` or in Java `AdminClient.describeCluster` to verify the cluster metadata